# I inputed 1 in a prime program and it isnt showing any output in C++

Tags: c++, primes

```
if(input == 2){
    std::cout << input << " is a prime number.\n";
}
else if(input % 2 != 0){
    for(int i = 3; i <= input; i+=2){
        if(input % i == 0){
            if(i == input){
                std::cout << input << " is a prime number\n";
            }
            else{
                std::cout << input << " is not a prime number.\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    std::cout << input << " is not a prime number.\n";
}
```

I try inputting 1 in this program and for some reason, it isnt showing any output.
According to the program it should be outputting "1 is not a prime number." but it isn't.
Any idea why?
This is in C++;

This is the terminal output.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\cpp class> cd "c:\Users\Administrator\cpp class\" ; if ($?) { g++ prime.cpp -o prime } ; if ($?) { .\prime }
___________PRIME_OR_NOT___________
Enter the number : 1
PS C:\Users\Administrator\cpp class>
```

I tried setting the input variable manually in the code and it doesnt work either.
I am expecting the program to output "1 is not a prime number." in the terminal.

Comment: Your 1st condition should be `if(input <= 2)`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and explain which part of it you expect to create that output. Also show the output you get instead please.

Comment: Your `for` loop is not executed because `i <= input` is false (which is `3 <= 1` ).  There are no `cout` statements after the `for` loop. Thus no output is seen.

Answer (score 1):

In the event that your input is odd, which `1` is, all of your output occurs within loops. That first loop starts with `i = 3`, and loops as long as `i` is less than or equal to the input. But if the input is `1`, this loop never executes.

The following would rectify that issue.

```
if (input <= 2) {
    std::cout << input << " is a prime number.\n";
}
else if (input % 2 != 0) {
    for (int i = 3; i <= input; i += 2) {
        if (input % i == 0) {
            if (i == input) {
                std::cout << input << " is a prime number\n";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << input << " is not a prime number.\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << input << " is not a prime number.\n";
}
```

Comment: but 1 is not a prime number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input == 2){
    std::cout << input << " is a prime number\n";
}
else if(input < 2){
    std::cout << input << " is not a prime number\n";
}
else if(input % 2 != 0){
    for(int i = 3; i <= input; i+=2){
        if(input % i == 0){
            if(i == input){
                std::cout << input << " is a prime number\n";
            }
            else{
                std::cout << input << " is not a prime number.\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    std::cout << input << " is not a prime number.\n";
}
```

Its working now. I changed the first if code block to this if code block.

Thanks Chris.

Comment: There's no need to nest here. Have your conditional for `input == 2` and add an `else if (input < 2)` condition.